# Showing an image only if content view of UITextView is larger than its fame

Tags: ios, uitextview, scrollview

I am doing a project in which I want show an image if the text doesn't fits to the UITextView frame.

I am using the following code

```
  if (self.textView.contentSize.height >= self.TextView.bounds.size.height)
{
    self.imageView.hidden = NO;
}
```

I am using Autolayout also. Does it cause such issues

And one more thing is that, when I print NSLog, the value of contentSize.height was NOT changing according to the text UITextView was showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, if you assign text to textView and check its size in the next instruction in viewControllers viewDidLoad, it wont work.It will just give you what contentSize you had set.

Check the contentSize in **viewDidAppear** of ViewController, and it will work.
It worked for me.
Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to check the height of multi line text according to the font size used

```
+  (CGSize) calculateLabelHeightWith:(CGFloat)width text:(NSString*)textString
{
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(width, 9999);
    CGSize size = [textString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24]
                         constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size;
}
```

you need to know

- width of text feild
- string
- font
- font size

iOS7

```
CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:<text Feild Size>
                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont stuff here]}
                                 context:nil];

CGSize size = textRect.size;
```

Comment: [textString sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode:];
 is Deprecated in iOS 7.0 https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: THank you for responding quickly